# How can I query customized board column change date in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs

I know you can query by state change date instead of column change date if you are using the default columns that match the state. But our TFS board columns are custom. I can see the board column changes in the work item history, so they are clearly stored somewhere. I'm happy with help on a query or if there is some way to do it through the query tool that I haven't figured out.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to query based on the date that a work item moved from one column to another?

Comment: Specifically I'm looking for the list of work items that moved into a column within a date range.

Answer (score 1):

You can only list work items with [Kanban query fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/track/query-by-workflow-changes#list-items-based-on-kanban-board-changes), but can't get column change date.

You need to use [TFS api](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/revisions#get-a-list-of-work-items-revisions) to get work items revisions, and check whether `System.BoardColumn` field is changed in any revision.